# Running ios app under development on devices without Xcode and USB cable

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, device

I'm a new iOS Developer Program member.

Now, I need to check my app on devices (iPhone and iPad).

EDIT : Everything work fine under Simulator.

I can run the app on devices when I lauch it from Xcode, and when devices are connected with USB cable.

But, the app crash when I launch it directly from the device springboard.

EDIT : A little precision : my App launch from the springboard, but when I touch somewhere in the screen (buttons or tableViewcell), the App stop.

Is it a normal behavior ?

Do I have to use ad-hoc technology to run my development app on my devices without Xcode and USB cable ?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This is not normal behaviour - you should be able to run the app normally once disconnected. I'll leave it to someone else to suggest a solution though, as I've never encountered this problem.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly closing your app from running in the background before trying to launch it? What I am fearing is you run it from Xcode unplug (without properly stopping it) and then attempting to open your app. That would definitely cause a crash as you unplugged the running app from its debugger.

Comment: This is not normal, more likely it's a bug in your app. Using ad hoc would not solve the problem. Try to debug your app.

Comment: check the crash log out of XCode(most likely, its a memory issue).

Comment: Try https://testflightapp.com/, here you can test ad-hoc release builds. Also, its not normal that your app crash when its launched directly from the device springboard. Hope this info helps you..

Comment: Thank you all! A little precision : my App launch from the springboard, but when I touch somewhere in the screen (buttons or tableViewcell), the App stop.

Comment: its a bug in your app then..., use breakpoints to find where actually it crashed also look at console for the error which leads app to crash

Comment: If I run the app from Xcode, all is ok. If I unplugged the USB cable, the app crash... :-/

Comment: I've found the origin of the crash. As @Ishank said, it was a (deep) memory issue. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a normal behavior. There must be bugs in your application. apps you developed can run just same as installed from appstore.

After you failed launch the app from springboard, connect the device again, in xcode organizer , check the device logs of the application.

Comment: It seems to be a 'Views Hierarchy' problem. I'm using a storyboard for my app. I can't post reply with log and image of my storyboard beginning for now (not enough reputation)...

Comment: check your button action code and table view cell did select method, if there're simulator specific code?

Comment: I've no buttons on this view. The didSelectRowAtIndexPath is ok within the simulator. I suspect a storyboard segue problem. All my views are linked with a segue (push) between a button and a tableView. But my first view doesn't have any buttons. And no segue between the tableView and the details view. I push the view within code. Any idea ?

Comment: I've just tried to comment all code within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and my app still crash... :(

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me, it was a twited memory issue.

As I omitted to turn the NSZombieEnabled option off, some memory issues don't occur in the simulator, but only on devices.

Thanks to all !